# Como crear saltos de linea segun X numero de palabras

Tags: javascript

Lo que quieor hacer es lo siguiente , el usuario colocara una oracion quiero un salto de linea cada 3 palabras peor no se como lograrlo e intentado con split pero si me pueden ayudar seria grandioso

```js
 let tex = document.getElementById('tex_input').value
    word.innerHTML = help //cada 3 palabras un salto de linea
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    <p id="word">Blanca por dentro<br>
        verde por fuera <br>
        Si no sabes,<br>
        espera.</p>
 </div>
<div id="div_mostrar_two" style="display: none">
    <textarea name="comentarios" placeholder="Adivinanza" id="help_input" class="input_general_texarea" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resumen**

> El programa recibe un texto y lo divide en palabras, para formar una nueva cadena de texto con saltos de línea cada 3 palabras.

**Explicación**

> - Declaro una variable `palabras` que almacena el `array de strings` que devuelve el método `split()`.
> - Declaro una variable `contador` que almacena el contador de palabras
> - Reinicio el parametro `texto` para generar el texto nuevo.
> - Recorro el `array de strings palabras`.
> - Agrego a la variable `texto` la palabra actual del `array palabras` y un espacio.
> - Incremento el `contador` de palabras.
> - `Si` el `contador es igual a 3`, agrego un salto de línea y `reinicio el contador a 0`.
> - Retorno el `texto`.

**Solución**

```javascript
const texto = document.getElementById('word');

function saltoDeLinea(texto) {
    let palabras = texto.split(' ');
    let contador = 0;
    texto = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
        texto += palabras[i] + ' ';
        contador++;
        if (contador === 3) {
            texto += '<br>';
            contador = 0;
        }
    } 
    return texto;
}

texto.innerHTML = saltoDeLinea(texto.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Trata de agregar una explicación relevante de la solución propuesta. Recuerda que no se responden preguntas solo para usuarios avanzados.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por la aclaración.